# Loading jquery into safari extension

Tags: safari-extension

I am unable to load jquery into my safari extensions injected script

Below is my injected script injected.js and the alert is never fired. typeof(jQuery) returns undefined. I even tried adding the script as a "script" node in document.head and nothing is working. My global html file is basically an empty file. I tried some of the suggestion mentioned in the other thread too.

```
document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleSelectedText, false);

element = document.createElement('bubble');
element.id = 'P';
element.appendChild(document.createElement('googlesearch'));
element.style.display = 'none';
document.body.insertBefore(element, document.body.firstChild); 

if($(document))
{
    alert('js laoded');
}
```

[image: Below I have added it as a start script, then my injected script is loaded]

Comment: Solution was I had to restart safari after setting the script in Developer Extension.

Answer (score 2):

Solution was I had to restart the browser after I set the script.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. Did you remember to grant your extension access to at least some websites? That setting is in the Extension Builder too:

[image: extension website access]

Comment: Yes I've done that. Let me attach my infolist.pl file

Comment: I have no idea how, I just tried and its working for me too now :). Thanks